# How to get list items by index in freemarker template?

Tags: java, templates, freemarker, template-engine

Is there a way to get list item by index in freemarker template, maybe something like this:

```
<#assign i = 1>
${fields}[i]
```

i'm new to freemarker.

Comment: To access a variable in that list ${fields[i].variableName}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can easily use the index to get at an item like `${fields[i]}`.  You might want to loop over the indexes using something like:

```
<#list 0..fields?size-1 as i>
${fields[i]}
</#list>
```

Alternatively, you can just list over a sequence without the index like:

```
<#list fields as field>
${field}
</#list>
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use inbuilt index property of FMT:
eg:

```
<#list ['a', 'b', 'c'] as i> ${i?index}: ${i} </#list>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tested [online](https://try.freemarker.apache.org/), the following works well.

**Input:**

```
someList = ["2019-12-16", 3]
```

**Template:**

```
<ul> 
   <li>${someList[0]}</li>
   <li>${someList[1]}</li>
</ul>
```

**Output:**

```
<ul> 
   <li>2019-12-16</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```